# Incorrect canvas width value

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I thought that the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log Canvas Width</title>
    <style>
        #canvas {
            background: #888888;
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function draw() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
                         context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            document.write(canvas.width);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="draw();">
        <canvas id='canvas'>
            Canvas not supported
        </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

prints 300 rather than 600 because `<body onload="draw();">` makes the script run at page loading, and at that time the canvas has not yet caught the revised value (600).

But then I modify the code to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log Canvas Width</title>
    <style>
        #canvas {
            background: #888888;
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='canvas'>
        Canvas not supported
    </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
                     context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        document.write(canvas.width);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I'm imagining that the script runs after the canvas has taken the attribute from the embedded style and that I will see 600. Not true. I still get 300, even though the canvas duly has width = 600. What is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`canvas.width` and `canvas.style.width` are two different things. In most of the cases, they should be equal, but they can also be different for achieving various effects. 300 you're getting is the canvas default width.

`canvas.width` is the actual number of pixels that are available inside the canvas, while `canvas.style.width` is the width of the HTML element, thus you can see stretching, pixelation, etc, if the two numbers are different.

---

Here are a couple of answers that describe the issue in more detail:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28142612/965907
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34539170/965907
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28879318/965907

Comment: Ah, they're accessible via canvas.style.. thanks! I had read (and, sure enough, forgotten) about CSS not affecting something or other. It didn't make sense. Now I'm gathering that canvas.width specifies the *logical* width, whereas CSS specifies the actual size in the browser. Yet the actual scanline rendering happens on the canvas. It is merely scaled to fit the CSS dimensions. Does it sound like I'm now getting it?

Comment: That's absolutely correct! Sorry I forgot to mention that `canvas.style` actually stands for the CSS style, no matter how and where it's set.

Answer (score 5):

> Default width of canvas is `300 x 150` [[Ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-author-20120329/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element)]. Canvas does not consider `css` defined with. Either you defined `width/heigh` attributes or assign those values as `properties` of `canvas` element.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
alert(canvas.width);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='600'>
  Canvas not supported
</canvas>
```

**OR**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 600;
alert(canvas.width);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'>
  Canvas not supported
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that setting the canvas width and height equal to the style width and height helped me with the calculations later.
Like:

```
canvas.width = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
canvas.height = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```